# External hard drive

Tags: hard-drive, external-hdd

I have an internal hard drive that was a dual boot of Windows and Ubuntu 12.04 and I would like to use it as an external hard drive, but if I mount it using ubuntu machine I can see different folders but can't find any of my documents, if using windows I cannot actually see it open.

[image: A snapshot of my screen]

Any idea how to overcome that or at least, how to format it so I can use it as external hd.

Comment: Two things: In all the files you see, can you click on a folder called home. Do you then see the files? Are the files on your ubuntu or on windows?

Comment: In all the files I see there are no home folders. I can see both ubuntu and windows folders but can't access any of the documents

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what you see? (without too much personal info of course)

Comment: ![A snapshot of my screen][1]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/6U8Wz.png

Comment: Ok can you tell us what you expected to see? I mean what files are you looking for?

Comment: Ok,under users I am expecting to see MyDocuments as a Folder and if opened should give me a list of all documents I had before removing  as internal hard drive. Note the drive can be recognized on the left hand side of the screenshot, with 3 different components DATA, 410GB Volume and 209MB Volume

Comment: The documents you worked on in Ubuntu are normally not going to be in that folder. Users is `home` in ubuntu. Can you search for a file you know you created in ubuntu and see whether that helps?

Comment: The question was I wanted to use an internal hard drive that I removed from a laptop as an external, but the issue was I had two operating systems on it, Win7 and Ubuntu and if connected as external I could see the snapshot shown above. Under users I was expecting to have documents that I have been working on but such is not the case all folders in shortcut formats (like documents and settings above) and they all indicate empty or have a single dekstop.ini file. So it seems I can't access any of my previous work. Hope its clear

Answer (score -2, accepted):

To format your drive open a terminal and run this

```
sudo apt-get install gparted
```

Once installed run it from the dash. Now find the drive whitch you want to format from the top right drop down. Then right click and unmount it, now right click and format to, then use NTFS if you need windows compatability, or ext-4 if you do not,as a file system and click the apply button (green tick).

THIS WILL DELETE ALL DATA ON YOUR DRIVE

Comment: Please do not follow this advice because, as mark says: it will delete all data on your drive. This is not a solution to your problem.

Comment: He asked "how to format the drive" it is a answer to his question a down vote is unnecessary

Comment: For me the question is insufficiently clear to answer it with the clarity you have answered it. Sorry for the downvote (of fake internet point), I'll see whether you have something valuable that should be upvoted, but this really deserves my downvote.

Comment: You are wrong did you not read his post ? Here is a direct quote "Any idea how to overcome that or at least, how to format it so I can use it as external hd"

Comment: If you really want to format that drive, then you have to update grub to delete any Windows entries. Open terminal and type ``sudo update-grub``

Comment: You are right mark, I did ask for formatting but would definitely use it as a last option

Comment: I suggest this as I beleve your drive is corrupted and will need formatting I suggest you to try a data recovery program on your drive to back it up first. You can try http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk to get you started

Comment: I think I will go ahead and format it, can you plzsuggest a data recovery program

Comment: Already did in these very comments, look up two

Answer (score 0):

Your windows documents will be in the folder **Users\Documents and Settings\(username)**.  Your Ubuntu documents will be in the folder **/home/(username)**.  Back up the files you want to keep, and then format the entire drive as NTFS.  Then copy your documents back in.

BTW, the screenshot you posted is showing your Windows partition only.  Your Ubuntu partition is probably either the "732GB Volume" or the "41 GB volume" on the left-hand side.  (Different partitions show up as different volumes.)

Comment: Thanks, but the 732GB is a partition of the actual device am using to save work and can be seen both in windows and ubuntu. The different partitions for the external hd are DATA, 410GB and 209MB

Comment: @Julia ok, then click whichever one is your Ubuntu partition and your user files should be in /home/username.